Make a curved corner in the inside in CSS
I am currently developing a web app for blogs using ReactJS. I am currently focusing on styling, and I am encountering an issue with making my background visible inside a div that has a colored background. I have been looking on internet, MDN Web Docs, GeeksForGeeks, and using chatGPT, but nothing, I can't find the solution.
This is my interface :

This is my issue :

As you can see, I'm attempting to create a curved shape next to the arrow using two squares: square1, which is dark cyan in the image, corresponds to the colorful curve; and square2, which is dark, corresponds to the square with rounded corners.
However, you may notice that square2 is present, but I don't want it to be visible to the user. I want square1 to appear as a simple curve, allowing the background to be visible outside of it
Code
The squares and arrow are in Filter component :
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './css/Filter.css';

function Filter() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(true);

  const handleFilterArrowButtonClick = () => {
    setIsActive((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const getArrowClassName = () => {
    return isActive ? 'isActive' : 'isInactive';
  };

  return (
    <div className='filter'>
      <div className={`filter-container ${getArrowClassName()}`}>
        ...
      </div>
      <div className='arrow-container' onClick={handleFilterArrowButtonClick}>
        <div className='square square-left'></div>
        <div className='arrow-rectangle'>
          <div className='arrow-triangle'></div>
        </div>
        <div className='square square-right'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Filter;

Its css file :
.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.filter-container {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  transition: width 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease, border-radius 0.3s ease;
  overflow: hidden; /* To hide the content when collapsed */
}

.isActive {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

.isInactive {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.arrow-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto; 
}

.square {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  position: relative;
}

.square::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #1a2130;
}

.square-left::before {
  border-radius: 0 65% 0 0;
}

.square-right::before {
  border-radius: 65% 0 0 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.arrow-rectangle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid aliceblue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px; /* Adjust to position inside the rectangle */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

 ...

The App component where is called Filter component :
import './App.css';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Filter from './components/Filter';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Navbar />
      <Filter />
      <div className='content'>
        <Home />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}



body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto; 
}

.square {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  position: relative;
}

.square::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #1a2130;
}

.square-left::before {
  border-radius: 0 65% 0 0;
}

.square-right::before {
  border-radius: 65% 0 0 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.arrow-rectangle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid aliceblue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px; /* Adjust to position inside the rectangle */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Filter Component</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='filter'>
    <div class='arrow-container'>
      <div class='square square-left'></div>
      <div class='arrow-rectangle'>
        <div class='arrow-triangle'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='square square-right'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



So the issue is purely graphical; I don't have any errors or warnings in the console, and the code is functioning correctly. However, I'm unsure how to make the background visible through the curved corner that I've created.
I'm sorry for any incovenience about this topic, if there is any information missing, don't hesitate. Thank you in advance for your help.

It might help to provide a working example (i.e. the HTML/CSS output) to demonstrate the issue.

Is it because I put a lot of code, or the description of the issue isn't clear that is a problem ? ^^

I just updated the question, to be clear and keep the necessary code.

The code and description are fine. Since this seems like a CSS issue, I would just find a demo that I can play with on here to be helpful.

Oh sorry, I didn't know tha we could do that, ok i do it =D

I added the code with html css since it's a style issue ^^

please check the https://stackoverflow.com/a/78616079/20821401 this CSS.

Please modify your css :-
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.square {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.square::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  border-radius: 0 65% 0 0;
}

.arrow-rectangle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid aliceblue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

